# Function that grows as fast as sum of previous values

Tags: limits, summation, examples-counterexamples

Does there exist a strictly positive, monotonically increasing function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{f(k)}{f(n)} = 1
$$
My guess is that there shouldn't exist such a function, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: Something along the line of $f(n) = e^n$ should work actually, I guess

Comment: I don't think that will work. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{n - 1}}{e^n} = \frac{1}{e}$, so the limit should be at least as large as $1 + \frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: But the idea is sound. The faster the function grows, the closer the sum should be to $1$.

Comment: Are you interested in *previous* values? Your expression includes the current value as well. In the first case, $2^n$ will do. In the second case, you just need something extremely fast growing, probably $2^{2^n}$ will do.

Comment: What do you mean by previous values? To clarify, the limit I'm considering is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{f(n)} \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)$. I just chose to write the limit with the $f(n)$ inside the summation because it helped me to think about the problem, but it shouldn't matter which way you write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sum, $k$ may be equal to $n$, so we must have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)}{f(n)}+1=1$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)}{f(n)}=0$$
The factorial numbers nicely satisfy this relation: set $f(n)=n!$, and notice that for $n>2$, $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k!}{n!}<\frac2n$, so the desired limit is satisfied.

---

If $f(n)$ is not included in the summation, $2^n$ will suffice, as pointed out by Mees de Vries in the question comments.

Comment: I've never seen that last inequality before. Do you have a quick proof of it?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins It may be easily proved via induction.

Comment: Just checked, and you're right: it is easily proved via induction. Thank you for your answer. I really wasn't expecting that such a function would exist!